# Response is not available in this context when SessionState with mode="Custom"

Tags: azure

This is what the exception I am getting while running an Web project which is migrated from Asp.net to Windows Azure Cloud. That too working fine if the sessionstate in web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />.
```

But if i make the web.config sessionstate to

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AzureCacheSessionStoreProvider" >
      <providers>
        <add name="AzureCacheSessionStoreProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" useBlobMode="true" dataCacheClientName="default"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

it is giving the the following exception. There is no clue regarding the exception. Please someone help at the earliest.

Exception:

```
{"Response is not available in this context."}
    [System.Web.HttpException]: {"Response is not available in this context."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Response is not available in this context."
    Source: "System.Web"

    StackTrace: "   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Response()\r\n   at Writehome_aspxToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declare
dType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WritePlaceHolderToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.S
erializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfControlToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , Collection
DataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDec
laredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   a
t System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteSerializableSessionStateStoreDataToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContract contract, Hashtable surrogateDataContracts)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWr
iteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.NetDataContractCacheObjectSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object value)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheObjectSerializationProvider.SerializeUserObject(Object userObject, Boolean isCompressionEnabled, ValueFlagsVersion flagsType)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SerializeValue(Object obj)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle,
 TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalPutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass9c.<PutAndUnlock>b__9b()\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MonitoringListenerFactory.EmptyListener.Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.IMonitoringListener.Listen[TResult](Func`1 innerDelegate)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheWrapper.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<PutAndUnlock>b__1b()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFo
rwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass31`1.<PerformCacheOperation>b__30()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheRetryWrapper.PerformCacheOperation(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PerformCacheOperation[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.BlobBasedSessionStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContextBase context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Exec
ute()\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)"
    TargetSite: {System.Web.HttpResponse get_Response()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all your help, finnally i have found out the reason for the issue. Issue occured because I was trying to store the the System.Web.UI.WebControls into a session.

Since not all System.Web.UI.WebControls are serilizable, so avoid storind WebControls to session.

Happy coding..